# Condition with AND in PlaceHolder

Tags: asp.net

I have a code that makes visibility conditions in a placeholder like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("VideoURL").ToString() != "" %>'>
```

And it works very well.

I want to add more conditions with the **AND** operator in like this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("VideoURL").ToString() != "" AND Eval("ImageURL").ToString() != "" %>'>
```

But, he shows me this error: **CS1026:) expected**

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` isn't a valid logical operator in C#, and I wouldn't expect it to work on C# based ASPX markup. Instead, use the `&&` operator.